# Prove the sum and intersection of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=(1-\frac{1}{n}, 3-\frac{(-1)^n}{n})$ then I need to find sum and intersection.

If n is even then we have $A=(1-\frac{1}{n}, 3-\frac{1}{n})$ if its odd then $A=(1-\frac{1}{n}, 3+\frac{1}{n})$

I think $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A=(0,4)$ $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A = [1,   2\frac{1}{2})$ but I don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have looks fine to me. Since $A$ depends on $n$ it might be easier to write
$$
A_n = \left(1-\frac{1}{n},3-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right).
$$
For the union, observe that $A_1 = (0,4)$, and that $A_n \subset A_1$ for all $n > 1$. So $\bigcup_n A_n = A_1 = (0,4)$.

For the intersection, suppose $x \in \bigcap_n A_n$. Then $x > 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z^+$, which implies that $x \geq 1$. Also, $x \in A_2$, which means $x < 3 - \frac{1}{2} = 2\frac{1}{2}$. So $x \in [1,2\frac{1}{2})$.

The other direction: suppose $x \in [1,2\frac{1}{2})$. Then
$$
x \geq 1 > 1-\frac{1}{n}
$$
for all $n \in \Bbb Z^+$. Also,
$$
x < 2\frac{1}{2} \leq 3 - \frac{1}{n} \leq 3 - \frac{(-1)^n}{n}
$$
for all $n \in \Bbb Z^+$. So $x  \in A_n$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z^+$, and $x \in \bigcap_n A_n$.